# Is there a term for someone who uses words like "thee" & "thine" in their daily language?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

I'm curious if there is a word for someone who uses "thee" or "thine" or other words like these in their daily language?

Comment: I’d go for either _bonkers_ or _Methusalem_? Nobody uses _thou/thee/thy/thine_ in normal speech anymore, or has for the past couple of centuries, so anyone who does is either a bit of a loony or several centuries old.

Comment: They're called *Yorkshiremen* although they may be women too - it's not a gender specific term nowadays. You could call them *Yorkshirefolk* instead if you wish :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Or they might be from Yorkshire ... :)

Comment: @Araucaria That is true. Good point. Though I have to admit I’ve never heard a Yorkshireman actually distinguish _thou/thee/thy/thine_ very clearly—they all seem to become just [ðə] or [ða] indiscriminately in my experience.

Comment: Antediluvian, perhaps?!

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? My first reaction was that "words like these" are  archaic words, but I'm not totally sure if you mean something more specific. Would the same kind of person also say things like "Methinks" or "yclept"?

Comment: The generous response would be to refer to them in kind.

Comment: "Time travellers"?

Comment: Ostentatious, perhaps?

Comment: Renaissance fair cosplayers.

Comment: @Jim if it hadn't been for The Big Bang Theory, and [a recent answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247964/what-do-you-call-someone-who-dresses-strangely-or-extravagantly/247991#247991) by Joe Blow, I would not have the faintest idea what you were talking about. :)

Comment: I think "tool" is the word you're looking for.

Comment: There are a few members of the Society of Friends ("Quakers") who still use *thee* and *thy* with each other. They are seeking to preserve the implication of closeness and intimacy of the forms. Otherwise,  (excluding events sponsored by the Society for Creative Anachronism) the only place we find these forms used (in the US) is in church, where the language is literally carven in stone

Comment: If they're doing it to sound smart, you could say "pretentious".

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the exact word for such people, but such usage is Archaism, so consequently, Archaist can be used to describe such people, where Anarchistic would be the ability to speak Archaic language.

Comment: **Archaist**. Perfect.

Comment: s/Anarchistic/Archaistic/?